# Django override QuerySet for pk

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-orm, djongo

I'm using [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/) in order to connect my Django Rest Framework project to MongoDB,

As MongoDB using `_id` as its primary key, I changed my models like this:

```py
from djongo import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

When I query data from database, the type of `_id` will be `bson.objectid.ObjectId`

So any time I want to query anything, I should do it like this:

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from myapp.models import MyModel

MyModel.objects.get(pk=ObjectId('606e91bd371197379e9bf919'))
# or
MyModel.objects.filter(_id=ObjectId('606e91bd371197379e9bf919'))
```

and if I use `MyModel.objects.filter(pk='606e91bd371197379e9bf919')` it can't find the data in database

This additional `ObjectId` which is required for any query makes many problems because none of the pre-existing classes (like Forms, Views, Django Rest Framework Serializers, ....) act like that, so I should override all of them, and this cause many code duplications,

Is there a way to override any of `Q`/`QuerySet`/`Model`/`Model Meta Class` or a wrapper or anything else to apply the additional `ObjectId` for  querying `pk`/`id`/`_id` field and solve this problem?

Is a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I would override the default manager `get` and `filter` methods to check if `pk` and/or `_id` are passed as kwargs and cast the value to `ObjectId`.

Here is an example overriding the get method and changing the `pk` value to an ObjectId.

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        if pk:
            kwargs['pk'] = ObjectId(pk)
        return super().get(**kwargs)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Comment: In this way, I should override every method in manager, `filter`, `get`, `exclude`, ...

Comment: Also, This way I can't filter relations with something like `fieldname__id` or similar.